# When upgrade MySQL from 5.7.18 to 5.7.30, meet a error

Tags: mysql

everyone,my current server information like below:

- OS version is: **3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64**
- Current mysql version is: **mysqld  Ver 5.7.18 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server (GPL))**

when i upgrade MySQL from 5.7.18 to 5.7.30, the console print a lot of errors like below:
/sbin/ldconfig: File /lib64/libevent_extra-2.0.so.5 is empty, not checked

And I want to known why this happend,how to fix it

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=85480

Comment: From that link, *"Those errors mean that you have a missing installation of certain packages. If you find and reinstall those packages by:

`pacman -Syyf <PACKAGE_NAME_HERE>`

you'll reinstall and dismiss those errors."*

Comment: Firstly,thank you. but current used OS is: **CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)** @RobertHarvey

Comment: I would imagine that the procedure to correct this problem is the same.